# Trying to add top margin to a div, but its not responding

Tags: css, margin

The div class circle renders on the right had page but even adding margin:0 auto; nothing works it just stays there what gives.

Here is my html/php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

    <header>
        <h1><span class="tech">TECH</span><span class="basics">BASICS</span></h1>
        <h2>Personal Tech Specialists</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="circle"></div>

</div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is my css

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    background: #BAE4FF;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}

nav .menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav .menu li {
    padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
    display: none;
}

nav .menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.1em;
}

nav .menu .blog {
    background: #1669B5;
}

nav .menu .contact {
    background: #3892E3;
}

nav #touchNav {
    background: #48B4EF;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

header h1 .tech {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 3.5px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

header h1 .basics {
    color: #48B5EF;
    margin-left: 3.5px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

.circle {
    margin-top: 100px;
    clear: both;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #48B5EF;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: why you are using margin two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add position tag.. u can use fixed as position or relative whatever suits your needs.. to the .circle class.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how position relative fixed this issue. Will you please clarify? Maybe I don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your circle class margins are funny.

Try this instead:

```
.circle {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  clear: both;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #48B5EF;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5w3G/1/

One should think that this will work too but trust the first one more:

```
.circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  clear: both;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #48B5EF;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5w3G/2/

CSS means *Cascading* style sheets. Cascading means that if one property is defined two or more times for the same element then the property read last is applied. So if you define margin on circle, then again latter in the same style sheet, then again later in a second style sheet with its rel link after the first in the head section, then in the head section itself after the rel links in a style tag, then again inline on the element itself, then the inline value is used. In fact that is the order they are used.

Comment: Nice eye! +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

it would be beeter to have an example of page when you ask about css,
but here is the real problem for you
in css margin top does not work as you expect.
its not making a space on the top of your elements unless all the elements be in the same parent z-index (or simpler i mean they all have one parent) i.e all `li`'s within a `ul`.
the top margin affects space between `li`'s not between `li` and `ul`.
for making that you should give the `ul` a `padding-top`.
  Hope it helps

Comment: This is actually incorrect. While Z-index may be a factor in determining margin, it does not require that all elements are within the same z-index to have the desired effect. Margin is most often determined by relation to non-absolutely positioned siblings, and parents.